# FirebaseFirestore not responding to create delete update

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The error I am getting :

> Considering local module
> com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module
> com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
> W/ProviderInstaller( 4876): Failed to load providerinstaller module:
> No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite
> found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0. W/Firestore( 4876):
> (24.7.0) [WriteStream]: (860add4) Stream closed with status:
> Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=No document to update:
> projects/nvn-app/databases/(default)/documents/users/6hrXonUrihWYdqbY5GwwI1mOj952/movies/00a6b260-4f1b-11ee-bc9c-bf986dd3ed09,
> cause=null}. E/flutter ( 4876):
> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: Unhandled error [cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested
> document was not found. occurred in Instance of 'NoteFormBloc'.

Now I am giving the file which interacts with firebaseFirestore :

```
@LazySingleton(as: INoteRepository)
class NoteRepository implements INoteRepository {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore;

  NoteRepository(this._firebaseFirestore);
  @override
  Future<Either<NoteFailure, Unit>> create(Movie list) async{
      try {
      final userDoc = await _firebaseFirestore.userDocument();
      final listDto = MoviesDto.fromDomain(list);

      await userDoc.moviecollection.doc(listDto.id).set(listDto.toJson());

      return right(unit);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.message!.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
        return left(const NoteFailure.insufficientPermission());
      } else {
        return left(const NoteFailure.unexpected());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<NoteFailure, Unit>> delete(Movie list) async{
     try {
      final userDoc = await _firebaseFirestore.userDocument();
      final listDto = MoviesDto.fromDomain(list);

      await userDoc.moviecollection.doc(listDto.id).delete();

      return right(unit);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.message!.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
        return left(const NoteFailure.insufficientPermission());
      }else if(e.message!.contains('NOT_FOUND')) {
        return left(const NoteFailure.unableToUpdate());
      } else {
        return left(const NoteFailure.unexpected());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<NoteFailure, Unit>> update(Movie list) async {
    try {
      final userDoc = await _firebaseFirestore.userDocument();
      final listDto = MoviesDto.fromDomain(list);

      await userDoc.moviecollection.doc(listDto.id).update(listDto.toJson());

      return right(unit);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.message!.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
        return left(const NoteFailure.insufficientPermission());
      }else if(e.message!.contains('NOT_FOUND')) {
        return left(const NoteFailure.unableToUpdate());
      }
       else {
        return left(const NoteFailure.unexpected());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Stream<Either<NoteFailure, KtList<Movie>>> watchAll() async* {
    final userDoc = await _firebaseFirestore.userDocument();
    yield* userDoc.moviecollection
        .orderBy('serverTimeStamp', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (snapshot) => right<NoteFailure, KtList<Movie>>(snapshot.docs
              .map((doc) => MoviesDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
              .toImmutableList()),
        )
        .onErrorReturnWith((e) {
          if (e is PlatformException &&
              e.message!.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
            return left(const NoteFailure.insufficientPermission());
          } else {
            return left(const NoteFailure.unexpected());
          }
        } as Either<NoteFailure, KtList<Movie>> Function(
            Object error, StackTrace stackTrace));
  }
```

If you want to know about NoteFormBloc :

```
@injectable
class NoteFormBloc extends Bloc<MovieFormEvent, MovieFormState> {
  final INoteRepository _noteRepository;

  NoteFormBloc(this._noteRepository) : super(MovieFormState.initial());

  @override
  Stream<MovieFormState> mapEventToState(
    MovieFormEvent event,
  ) async* {
    yield* event.map(
      initialized: (e) async* {
        yield e.initialNoteOption.fold(
          () => state,
          (initialMovie) => state.copyWith(
            mlist: initialMovie,
            isEditing: true,
          ),
        );
      },
      saved: (e) async* {
        Either<NoteFailure, Unit>? failureOrSuccess;

        yield state.copyWith(
          isSaving: true,
          saveFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
        );

        if (state.mlist.failureOption.isNone()) {
          failureOrSuccess = state.isEditing
              ? await _noteRepository.update(state.mlist)
              : await _noteRepository.create(state.mlist);
        }

        yield state.copyWith(
          isSaving: false,
          showErrorMessages: true,
          saveFailureOrSuccessOption: optionOf(failureOrSuccess),
        );
      },
      moviesChanged: (e) async* {
        yield state.copyWith(
          mlist: state.mlist.copyWith(body: MovieBody(e.bodystr)),
          //  (e.lists.map((primitive) => primitive.toDomain())),

          saveFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
        );
      },
      categoryChanged: (e) async* {
        yield state.copyWith(
          mlist: state.mlist.copyWith(body1: CategoryBody(e.bodystr1)),
        );
      },
      colorChanged: (e) async* {
        yield state.copyWith(
          mlist: state.mlist.copyWith(
              color: MovieColor(e.color)),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And finally if you want MoviesDto :

```
@freezed
abstract class MoviesDto implements _$MoviesDto {
  factory MoviesDto({
    String? id,
    String? body,
    String? body1,
    int? color,
  //  bool? done,
    @ServerTimeStampConverter() FieldValue? serverTimeStamp,
  }) = _MoviesDto;

  factory MoviesDto.fromDomain(Movie movie) {
    return MoviesDto(
      id: movie.id.getOrCrash(),
      body: movie.body.getOrCrash(),
     // done: movie.done,
      color: movie.color.getOrCrash().value,
      body1: movie.body1.getOrCrash(),
      serverTimeStamp:  FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    );
  }
  Movie toDomain() {
    return Movie(
      id: UniqueId.fromUniqueString(id!),
      body: MovieBody(body!),
      color: MovieColor(Color(color!)),
    //  done: done!,
      body1: CategoryBody(body1!),
    );
  }

  factory MoviesDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MoviesDtoFromJson(json);
      factory MoviesDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return MoviesDto.fromJson(doc.data as Map<String, dynamic>).copyWith(id:doc.id);
  }
}



class ServerTimeStampConverter implements JsonConverter<FieldValue, Object> {
  const ServerTimeStampConverter();
  @override
  FieldValue fromJson(Object json) {
    return FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  }

  @override
  Object toJson(FieldValue object) {
    return object;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is that the document you are trying to update does not exist in Firestore. When you call userDoc.moviecollection.doc(listDto.id).update(), if there is no document with that ID, it will throw a NOT_FOUND error. 1. Make sure the document ID you are passing in listDto.id matches an existing document ID in your moviecollection collection.2. Print out or log the listDto.id before doing the update to verify it is what you expect.